# How to show subscript text in value of p:commandLink

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I using `p:commandLink` of PrimeFaces having text CO2 in it and i want to show 2 as subscript. Can anybody tell me how to do that ? 
I already tried the below code but it doesn't work.

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="button" value="CO&lt;sup&gt;2&lt;/sup&gt; PER UNIT"/>
```

Comment: Just type a superscript 2 on your keyboard like ² (or copy-paste this one ;-) )… don't use html for that

Comment: @Kukeltje Thankyou but i said subscript not superscript :P

Comment: Answer stays the same different Character :-) ₂ or use html entities… http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2082/index.htm

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type it like you would in any other document editor like LibreOffice… ₂
Or use html entities

```
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#8322;
HTML Entity (hex)       &#x2082;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put HTML in link body.

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="button">CO<sup>2</sup> PER UNIT</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: That works, but using tags for styling is sooooo 1999 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the hex Html entity code instead of the sub html tag. Html entity code can be find at the below link:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2082/index.htm

Comment: @Kukeltje i posted the answer because you didn't post the answer earlier just commented on my post.

Comment: Yes, while preparing an answer (formatting and stuff) it was already there before you answered…  next time you can also ask if someone wants to post an answer. More polite im0